# TikZ draws function wrong. - How to make the code better?

Tags: tikz-pgf

We have got this TikZ code and it was said that this gives a different result to geogebra (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c68h3228155_need_help_with_tikz):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-7)--(0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[thick, domain=-1.5:2] plot(\x, {2.8*\x^4+4.77*\x^3-5.47*\x^2-7.61*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also asymptote gives another result as the TikZ, see post #2 in the link above.

What can be made better in TikZ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the expansion/precedence of the `-` when expanding `\x`. You can use [@Skillmon's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706728/38080) or add parenthesis:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-7)--(0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[thick, red, domain=-1.5:2] plot(\x, {2.8*(\x)^4+4.77*(\x)^3-5.47*(\x)^2-7.61*(\x)});
\draw[thick, dotted, domain=-1.5:2] plot(\x, {2.8*\x*\x*\x*\x+4.77*\x*\x*\x-5.47*\x*\x-7.61*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The sign precedence problem is even more evident if you do this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-7)--(0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[thick, red, domain=-1.5:2] plot(\x, {\x^2});
\draw[thick, dotted, domain=-1.5:2] plot(\x, {(\x)^2});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seem that when, say, `\x^2` is expanded and the value is negative, say -2, you obtain `-2^2`, which is interpreted as `-4`.

Answer (score 4):

Ti*k*Z has issues with the exponent function, use `\x*\x*\x*\x` instead of `\x^4`, etc.:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-7)--(0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[thick, domain=-1.5:2] plot(\x, {2.8*\x*\x*\x*\x+4.77*\x*\x*\x-5.47*\x*\x-7.61*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To further improve this: Reduce the `domain` (your function evaluated at x=2 equals 45.86), increase the `samples`, and maybe use `smooth`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-7)--(0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[thin, red, domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=101, smooth] plot(\x, {2.8*\x*\x*\x*\x+4.77*\x*\x*\x-5.47*\x*\x-7.61*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you still have numeric issues with your function (not the case for this function, but can happen), you might want to use the `pgfmath-xfp` package. It slows down your plots a bit, but using functions defined with it give much better resolution:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-7)--(0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[red, domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=101, smooth] plot(\x, {2.8*\x*\x*\x*\x+4.77*\x*\x*\x-5.47*\x*\x-7.61*\x});
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{myfunction}{1}
  {2.8*(#1)^4+4.77*(#1)^3-5.47*(#1)^2-7.61*(#1)}
\draw[very thin, blue, domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=101,smooth] plot(\x, {myfunction(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]